# Select mismatch column values from database

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008

I want to select and fetch all mismatch value of two table having same Column Name But Id, Name and City are different. I am Using Sql Server Management Studio

Table A:

```
id   Name   City

1    John   karachi

2    smith  Capetown

3     liza   Washington
```

Table B:

```
id   Name   City

7    Grey   Dubai

8    Clarke  Texas

9     liza   Washington
```

OUTPUT:

```
7    Grey   Dubai

8    Clarke  Texas
```

Answer (score 1):

This has been answered hundreds and hundreds of times. Not quite sure what you mean by "having same Column Name But Id, Name and City are different" but here are a couple of example of how you can do this.

You can use a left join where tablea is null,

```
select b.Name
    , b.City
from tableb b 
left join tablea a on a.name = b.name 
    and a.city = b.city
where a.name is null
```

You can use except.

```
select Name
    , City
from tableb
except
select Name
    , City
from tablea
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try the below query. Assuming that the `id` column is never `null`

```
select tb.* 
from tableB tb 
left join tableA ta 
on tb.Name=ta.Name and tb.City=ta.City
where ta.id is NULL
```

Link to demo sql fiddle: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/250e5/1

Comment: @JunaidMumtazAhmed Please do consider marking this as answer and/or upvote.  :)